# Removing last comma from out in PHP that is going into a javascript image pre-load script

Tags: php, javascript, image, preload

Hi I have a javascript pre-load script that incorporates a php command to pre-load uploaded images for a future onClick action. Anyway I am having trouble removing the LAST comma from the last image the pre-load script pulls from.

Here is the script:

```
<div style="display:hidden">
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
        var images = new Array()
        function preload() {
            for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
                images[i] = new Image()
                images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
            }
        }
        preload(

        <?php
            for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
                if (!empty($imgs[$i])) {
                    echo "'http://www.samplegallery.com/upload/image.php?img_source_url=" . $imgs[$i] . "&img_resize_to=500',";
                }
            }
        ?>

        )
    //--><!]]>
</script>
</div>
```

Anyway, I need to find out how to remove the last comma from the last image that is uploaded. Not sure how to do this. Please help me! BTW... the images don't have an extension since they are linking to a php image script that resizes them and places them into a watermark. Hope you guys can help me figure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think the other way! the comma could be at the start and then you remove it from the first one :)

```
if (!empty($imgs[$i])) {
  $comma = $i == 0? '' : ',';
  echo $comma."'http://www.samplegallery.com/upload/image.php?img_source_url=" . $imgs[$i] . "&img_resize_to=500'";
}
```

This way doesn't matter if `$i` is equal to 5, 8 or 139871!

Comment: Thank You! And that is a GREAT way to think. Thanks for helping me with this so quickly. Your an asset! I have incorporated this thinking for the future.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is using the php build in `implode()` function

```
<?php echo implode(',', $imgs); ?>
```

And if you want just the first 6 images, you can make an array like so

```
$imgs = array_slice($imgs, 0, 6);
```

So the whole thing must look like that:

```
preload(
<?php
    $imgs = array_slice($imgs, 0, 6);
    echo implode(',', $imgs);
?>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove the last comma from a string, just use this:

```
$string = rtrim($string, ",");
```

Comment: Note. in this case, if there is no comma, the last character would be deleted. Better still, we are use in this case that there would be a last character.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a slightly different approach to your problem? Whenever you want to pass data to JavaScript, JSON is probably the thing you want to generate. [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) helps you with that. Your script could look like:

```
var urls = <?php echo json_encode(array_values($imgs)); ?>;

var images = [];
function preload(urls) {
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        var url = 'http://www.samplegallery.com/upload/image.php?img_source_url='
            + encodeURIComponent(urls[i])
            + '&img_resize_to=500';

        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].src = url;
    }
}

preload(urls);
```

please note that I've taken the liberty of adding missing semicolons and `var` declarations to keep your variables local. I have added the `array_values()` call to make sure you're passing a numerically indexed array, rather than an associative array that would have resulted in an object literal `{ ... }` rather than an array literl `[ ... ]`.

I have also moved the URL building to JavaScript, as I didn't see a reason to keep it in PHP. If you need this to be in PHP and want to avoid the "manual" loop, look into [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map).

Please also note that I'm running your URL fragment through [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to properly escape whatever it is you're passing in.

A note on security: should your script at `/upload/image.php` accept arbitrary URLs (and or "local file resources"), consider white-listing the allowed domains and paths.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreach...

```
<?PHP 
    if ($count = count($imgs)) {
        foreach ($imgs as $key=>$img) {
            echo "http://www.samplegallery.com/upload/image.php?img_source_url="
            . $img . "&img_resize_to=500";
            if ($key < $count-1) echo ",";
        }
    }

?>
```